# Python CTypes Callback from a Structure Field

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I need to write a python call that has a callback that will be invoked by C function. The C header file has the following

```
...
typedef struct _myResponse {
   char * data, 
   void (*setResponseFunc)(const char * const  req, char ** dataptr);
} MyResponse_t
```

The C library calls the callback like this

```
void process(const char * const req , MyResponse_t *response) {
   response->SetResponseFunc("some request", &response->data);
}
```

Sample callback implementation of the callback in C:

```
void SetResponse(const char *respData, char **dataptr) {
      char *ptr = malloc(strlen(respData));
      strcpy(ptr, respData);
      *dataptr= ptr;
}
```

I then use ctypesgen to generate the python code. The generated file contains the following:

agent.py:

```
def String:
 ...

class struct__myResponse(Structure):
    pass

struct__myResponse.__slots__ = [
    'data',
    'SetResponseFunc',
]
struct__myResponse._fields_ = [
    ('data', String),
    ('SetResponseFunc', CFUNCTYPE(UNCHECKED(None), String, POINTER(String))),
]
```

this is how I tried to use it

```
CALLBACK_FUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_agent.UNCHECKED(None), agent.String, POINTER(agent.String))

def PyCopyResponse(a,b):
    print "XXXXXX" // here, I haven't tried to implement the proper code, just want to see if the callback is called from the C library

copy_response = CALLBACK_FUNC(PyCopyResponse)
```

Calling it

```
    agentResp = agent.MyResponse_t(None,copy_response)

    agent.process("some value",agentResp)
```

I dont' see my python callback implementation to be called at all. I have verified that the C library is calling the callback appropriately. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. The process takes a pointer to a structure, I was passing the structure directly.

```
data = agent.String() 
agentResp = agent.MyResponse_t(data,copy_response)
agentResp_p = pointer(agentResp)

agent.process("some value",agentResp_p)
```